# Building Core2.0 project in Visual Studio Team Services fails with numerous assembly import errors

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-devops, tfsbuild, asp.net-core-2.0

I have Build Definition

- .NET Core Restore
- .Net Core Build
- .Net Core Test
- .Net Core Publish
- Publish Artefact

While I was using Core1.1 it worked without any issue. But after upgrading project to Core2.0 it fails with multiple errors like

- `error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll' and 'C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.parallel\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll'`
- `error CS0433: The type 'TargetFrameworkAttribute' exists in both 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`
- `error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported`

Solution is perfectly building locally. I tried to add task `Use .NET Core runtime 2.0.0` in the beginning but without any success.

Comment: have you installed DotNetCore2.0 on your tfs server?

Comment: How can I do it other than task `Use .NET Core runtime 2.0.0`?

Comment: download and install it from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Install where? That Microsoft's TFS server with Microsoft's Build Agent. I have no any access to that.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Team Service not TFS, if so ,you better change the title of your question

Comment: Yeah, sorry, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add **.NET Core Tool Installer task** at the beginning of the build steps. Then install the **SDK** not only runtime. Then save your build definition and queue again.

[image]

Comment: I did have .NET Core Tool Installer task, but did not set SDK option, thought Runtime should be enough. Thanks.